# Get balanceOf tokens ERC721 (nethereum)

Tags: erc-721, nft, balances, nethereum

Just trying get count of uniswap NFT-s on 0x5794d36de0c21211a7906688981371132bd7c6f0 wallet

[image]

Step one: Get contract from adress 0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88 (Contract address for uniswap NFT)

```
 var contract = new Web3().Eth.GetContract(abiERC721, "0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88");
```

Step two: Ask this contract about balanceOf on wallet with number 0x5794d36de0c21211a7906688981371132bd7c6f0

```
var bal = contract.GetFunction("balanceOf").GetData("0x5794d36de0c21211a7906688981371132bd7c6f0");
```

ExpectationResult: 5 (we can see this on etherscan.io https://etherscan.io/token/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88?a=0x5794d36de0c21211a7906688981371132bd7c6f0#inventory)

My result:
0x70a082310000000000000000000000005794d36de0c21211a7906688981371132bd7c6f0

What am I doing wrong?

Full code

```
void GetCountOfTokensERC721()
    {
 string abiERC721 =
            "[{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"approve\",\"outputs\":[]," +
            "\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[" +
            "{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}" +
            "],\"name\":\"mint\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":" +
            "[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"safeTransferFrom\",\"outputs\":[]," +
            "\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\"" +
            ":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"bytes\",\"name\":\"_data\",\"type\":\"bytes\"}]," +
            "\"name\":\"safeTransferFrom\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":" +
            "[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"approved\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"name\":\"setApprovalForAll\"," +
            "\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"from\"," +
            "\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":" +
            "\"transferFrom\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\"," +
            "\"type\":\"constructor\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":" +
            "\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"Transfer\",\"type\":\"event\"}," +
            "{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"approved\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}]," +
            "\"name\":\"Approval\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":" +
            "[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"operator\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"approved\",\"type\":\"bool\"}]," +
            "\"name\":\"ApprovalForAll\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"}]," +
            "\"name\":\"balanceOf\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\"" +
            ":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}]," +
            "\"name\":\"getApproved\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":" +
            "\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"}," +
            "{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"operator\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"isApprovedForAll\",\"outputs\":" +
            "[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":" +
            "[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"ownerOf\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}]," +
            "\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bytes4\",\"name\":\"interfaceId\",\"type\":\"bytes4\"}]," +
            "\"name\":\"supportsInterface\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"}]\r\n";


        var contract = new Web3().Eth.GetContract(abiERC721, "0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88");
        
        var bal = contract.GetFunction("balanceOf").GetData("0x5794d36de0c21211a7906688981371132bd7c6f0");
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(bal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was found alternative solution.
This works fine and returns 5(real count)

```
    [Function("balanceOf", "uint256")]
    public class BalanceOfFunction : FunctionMessage
    {
        [Parameter("address", "_owner", 1)]
        public string Owner { get; set; }
    }




    public void QueryingForBalanceAtBlockNumberWorksAsExpected()
    {
        var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/7238211010344719ad14a89db874158c");

        string contractAddress = "0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88";

        string accountAddress = "0x5794d36de0c21211a7906688981371132bd7c6f0";

        var balanceOfFunctionMessage = new BalanceOfFunction()
        {
            Owner = accountAddress,
        };

        var balanceHandler = web3.Eth.GetContractQueryHandler<BalanceOfFunction>();


       var k =  balanceHandler.QueryAsync<BigInteger>(contractAddress, balanceOfFunctionMessage);
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(k.Result);
    }
```